# Por que no puedo insertar mas de 253 registros en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos estoy intentando insertar varias registros al mismo tiempo pero al generar este script solo me permite insertar un máximo de 253, en donde envío por medio de POST la cantidad de 500, que puedo estar haciendo mal?

```
if(isset($_POST["id_ncf"]))
{
    $ncf_d="1";
    $ncf_h="500";

    for($i=$ncf_d;$i<$ncf_h;$i++) {             
        mysql_query( "INSERT INTO ncf_inst (id_ncf,ncf_desde,ncf_hasta) VALUES ('$id','$i','$ncf_h')", $link) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($database);
    }
    header("Location: prueba.php");
}
```

Comment: Que error o mensaje te genera?

Comment: Todo depende de como tengas estructurada tu base de datos, o cuanta memoria te tenga permitida usar tu servicio.

Comment: hola que tal el Juan Pinzon, luego de unos segundo generando la insercion se pierde la conexion y me da el error HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Hola AnimationsNow , hago esto desde mi localhost, y tengo configurado mi server para permitirme importar archivos grandes de cualquier tamaño sin problemas, si no estoy equivocado, donde puedo ver esta informacion que me comentas?

Comment: Revisaste que los datos que estas intentando ingresar sean consistentes? Me la juego porque en el registro 254 estás ingresando datos inválidos. Revisa el log de tu servidor para conocer que errores te esta generando concretamente. El error 500 quiere decir que en tu script o sistema falló algo

Comment: OK lo reviso y lo posteo , Gracias hermanos!

Comment: se siente la buena vibra al ver cómo la familia de SOes se expande! Saludos, éxitos y bendiciones para todos :D que siga el desarrollo con todo el power 2.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hermanos muchas gracias , mi código esta bien, el error existía en la configuración de apache, por si le sirve a alguien , modifique el max_execution_time= 180, y listo lo inserto a la perfección,

Comment: Recuerda en marcar check tu respuesta como correcta, así se cierra la pregunta, saludos